# Replace text containing number in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to use `.replace()` function in JS to replace all occurencies of string `"{5}"`.

I had no problems with letters in brackets but numbers just dont work if I call:

```
mystring.replace(/{\5}/g,'replaced')
```

nothing happens. Please can you help me with right syntax?

Comment: Braces are special regex characters, you need to escape them, numbers are not.

Comment: Why not escape the number and not the brackets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with escaping. I'm pretty sure \5 is a backreference. You should instead be escaping the curly braces and not the number.

```
'Something {5} another thing'.replace(/\{5\}/g, 'replaced');
// -> Something replaced another thing
```

**Additional Note:** Just in case you're looking for a generalized string formatting solution, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format) with some truly awesome answers.

Comment: thanks, I got confused because ".replace(/{B}/g,'replaced')" worked without escaping brackets...

Answer (score 2):

Is there a special reason you are preceding the number with a backslash? If your intention is to match against the string "{5}", "{" and "}" are the special characters that should be escaped, not the character "5" itself!

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> A backslash that precedes a non-special character indicates that the next character is 
>   special and is not to be interpreted literally. For example, a 'b' without a preceding '\' generally matches lowercase 'b's wherever they occur. But a '\b' by itself doesn't match any character; it forms the special word boundary character.

The following code would work:

```
var str = "foo{5}bar{5}";
var newStr = str.replace(/\{5\}/g, "_test_");

console.log(newStr); // logs "foo_test_bar_test_"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mystring.replace(/\{5\}/g,'replaced');
```

You need to escape the curly brackets`\{` and `\}`.

***DEMO***

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/Gnsq3/